# Why won't my <script> tags execute the code inside of them?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Notepad ++ and this keeps on happening. I have this really simple code to test if the console works or not. When ever I run the program, I get the the code written in the browser. I am currently using Google Chrome. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.write("Hello World!");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!
Sorry if I formatted the code wrong, this is all new to me!

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your problem](http://jsbin.com/gocavaba/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: I hope it's because the gods are striking down your page for using `document.write`.

Comment: This question demonstrates little to no research effort.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried searching for a solution but could not find one!

Comment: Searching google for "test if the console works" https://www.google.com/search?q=test+if+the+console+works has the very first result pointing to another stackoverflow that would answer your question...

Comment: Did you check the file extension of your file ? Is it showing as (filename).html ? If not, rename it to a html file, and then try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "Hello, World!" to be written to the console, try using `console.log`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            console.log("Hello World!");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using `document.write` is for writing to the actual document, not the console, and [is generally considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Even if I use console.log it displays all the code on the webpage?

Comment: The console output can be viewed in the "developer console" and will not be visible to a regular user. If you're struggling to get your code to run at all, I'd rather go with ``alert("Hello World!")``, so it's easy to see if your code runs or not.

Comment: Code still does not run?

Answer (score 1):

you say "test if the console works" and then "I get the code written in the browser"...

You mean it's in the DOM like Quentin shows?

But you wanted it to the console? Then you need to use:

`console.log("Hello World!")`

or

`console.debug("Hello World!")`